# Add android platform on ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

Hello i get the project from http://reactorapps.io/blog/wordpress-api-ionic-app/
now i want add android platfrom , when i use ionic platform add android 
i get this error :
D:\downloadionic\reactorApp\reactorApp>ionic platform add android
 ✗ (node:9956) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
(node:1316) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
Creating android project...
C:\Users\Pouria.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^

Error: Please install Android target "android-19".
Hint: Run "android" from your command-line to open the SDK manager.
    at C:\Users\Pouria.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:174:19
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Pouria.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Pouria.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Pouria.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:760:13)
    at C:\Users\Pouria.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\Pouria.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
Error: C:\Users\Pouria.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Pouria\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)

what i must to do ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install Android KitKat (4.4.2) (API 19) through the Android SDK Manager.
You can do this by installing Android Studio and accessing the SDK Manager from within it. 
Select the packages that you need and hit 'Install'.